# Memory leak in c++/CLI code

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

The test app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String connectionString = "DSN=DotNetUltraLightDSII; UID=user; PWD=pass";
        String query = "select * from person";

        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            for (Int32 trial = 1; trial <= 100000; trial++)
            {
                if (0 == trial % 1000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing trial #{0:#,0}", trial);
                    GC.Collect();
                }

                using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                for (Int32 colIndex = 0; colIndex < reader.FieldCount; colIndex++)
                                {
                                    Object x = reader[colIndex];
                                    IDisposable d = x as IDisposable;
                                    if (null != d)
                                    {
                                        d.Dispose();
                                    }
                                    d = null;
                                    x = null;
                                }
                            }
                        } while (reader.NextResult());
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```

[Memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR1al.png)
[Heap Snapshot Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WESPy.png)

The memory usage just goes up over time. It seems like there are strong handles to the ULPersonTable but I cannot tell what exactly these strong handles are or where they are coming from. We are storing the instances of that type inside gcroot, but they seem to be destroyed. If someone could shed some light on this issue, that would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Do you really need `using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection))` inside the loop?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++/CLI? This is C# code.

Comment: @DavidYaw Because the driver implementation is in cpp cli and the memory leak seemingly happens in that layer.

Comment: @KenY-N I didn't write the repro code. Thirdparty

Comment: OK, so you think the problem is in the C++/CLI code.. We're going to need to see that if you want us to try to diagnose anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the problem. It was a pointer which wasn't being deleted properly.